# response при post-запросе

Tags: jquery, json, node.js

в ajax методом POST передаю данные регистрации, в js файле проверяю набранные пароли и хочу с помощью response.send отправить сообщение об ошибке, но ничего не происходит

```
app.post("/Users", jsonParser, function (request, response) {
if (request.body.Password != request.body._Password)
    {
        response.send("<h1>Пароли не совпадают</h1>");
        console.log("Пароли не совпадают!");
    }
```

как мне отправить сообщение об ошибке?

вот так я передаю данные (вдруг поможет решить мою проблему):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/users",
                data: JSON.stringify({UserName: UserName, Password: Password, _Password: _Password, Surname: Surname, Name: Name}),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(date);
                }
            });
```

Comment: а в консоле браузера (раздел сеть), что показывает?

Comment: пусто. ничего нет

Comment: вы видите исходящий POST запрос?

Comment: да, я использую эти данные и добавляю в БД. но отправить пользователю (браузеру) сообщение не получается. response просто ничего не делает и всё (как мне кажется, а может что-то и делает), а console.log прекрасно работает (в приведенном выше коде)

Comment: Если данные приходят в json, не надо ли их распарсить?\